# Flutter Firebase has not been correctly initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, program-entry-point

I want to use firebase in my app,
I write this:

```
main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(Myapp());
}
```

but I got error :

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 5331): Init ba5fb7d [ExoPlayerLib/2.17.0] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, unknown, 30]
E/flutter ( 5331): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
E/flutter ( 5331): 
E/flutter ( 5331): Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.
E/flutter ( 5331): 
E/flutter ( 5331): View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization
E/flutter ( 5331):     
E/flutter ( 5331): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:99:9)
E/flutter ( 5331): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5331): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:31)
```

and this:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

how can I solve it?

can anyone help me, please?

Comment: check your project by going console command ```firebase init``` see if its all there

Comment: error about  `await Firebase.initializeApp();`

Answer (score 1):

Does it solve the issue if you replace the initializeApp() line with the following?

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

Comment: yes but cant import package for `DefaultFirebaseOptions`

Comment: The FlutterFire documentation (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli) may be useful here. If you following along the steps, it provides details on how to generate a DefaultFirebaseOptions file, which mat solve this for you.